Justifying an unpublished identity of Gauss (apparently related to generalized hypergeometric series)
In an unpublished notebook of Gauss (Schedae 4), appear the following two infinite series identities:

$$1+(\frac{1}{2})^3x+(\frac{1\cdot3}{2\cdot4})^3x^2+(\frac{1\cdot3\cdot5}{2\cdot4\cdot6})^3x^3+\mathbb{etc} = (1+(\frac{1}{4})^2x+(\frac{1\cdot5}{4\cdot8})^2x^2+(\frac{1\cdot5\cdot9}{4\cdot8\cdot12})^2x^3+\mathbb{etc})^2$$

and:

$$(\frac{1}{2})^3\frac{1}{2}x^4+(\frac{1\cdot3}{2\cdot4})^3\frac{2}{3}x^6+(\frac{1\cdot3\cdot5}{2\cdot4\cdot6})^3\frac{3}{4}x^8+\mathbb{etc} = ((\frac{1}{2})^2x^2+(\frac{1\cdot3}{2\cdot4})^2\frac{1}{2}x^4+(\frac{1\cdot3\cdot7}{2\cdot4\cdot8})^2\frac{1}{3}x^6+\mathbb{etc})^2$$

The first identity was not published by Gauss during his lifetime, but was proved by him in 1799 and his proof appears on pp.191-193 of volume 10-1 of Gauss's Werke. It appears to be a case of Clausen's hypergeometric identity, proved by Clausen in 1828, which was the first result on generalized hypergeometric series. This identity expresses the square of a classical (Gaussian) hypergeometric series as a generalized hypergeometric series. In Gauss's first identity, the squared series is actually $_2F_1(\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4};1;x)$.
Thus, for the first identity I have the context, and I mentioned it here because it was written in Gauss's notebook a page before the second identity (and also in order to provide context).
Regarding the second identity, which can be reformulated as (I just write the pattern more explicitly):

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}((\prod_{k=1}^{n}\frac{2k-1}{2k})^3\cdot \frac{n}{n+1}x^{2(n+1)}) = (\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}((\prod_{k=1}^{n}\frac{2^k-1}{2^k})^2\cdot \frac{1}{n}x^{2n}))^2$$

, it was more difficult for me to generate the squared series by putting certain parameters in the hypergeometric function $_2F_1(a,b;c;x)$, since the numerators and denominators appear to be related to a geometric progression ($2^k$) rather than an arithmetic progression (as in the classical hypergeometric series). So it will be great if anyone will be able to justify this identity in modern mathematical terms. If the proof is relatively difficult, I will also accept any answer that gives some information on the type of the second identity and provides some useful references (in articles/books)

To me a more plausible interpretation of the "etc" is the Clausen formula specialization
$$\tfrac{x^4}{2^4}\cdot _3F_2(\tfrac{3}{2},\tfrac{3}{2},\tfrac{3}{2};2,3;x^2)=\left(\tfrac{x^2}{2^2}\cdot_2F_1(\tfrac{3}{4},\tfrac{3}{4};2;x^2)\right)^2\text{,}$$ which would seem to make the question moot

@KBDave - thank you very much! I think you are right (I checked the resulting coefficients) and it was indeed a mistaken interpretation of mine (I did not recognize the general pattern correctly).  So I guess my question is not really needed...
